# Symbolic Integration Implementation

Tags: symbolic-math

I want to implement symbolic integration. To achieve this. I've learned from Prof. Patrick Winston's AI lecture that Matlab uses

- 12 safe transformation, like that constant out, sums, etc.
- 12 Heuristic transformation e.g., about sin x, cos x...
- and, a table that contains 26 anchors to the calculations.

he listed 4 of the safe transformation, 3 of the 12 heuristic transformations, and 3 of the 26 table.

What are those? or where can I find them?

Comment: A lot of symbolic integration rules can be found in the [Rubi repository IntegrationRules](https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi/tree/master/Rubi/IntegrationRules) also available in [PDF form](https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/IntegrationRules)

Comment: Thank you for the link. The rules, however, contains too much rules. AFAIK, the implementation requires only 40 rules to integrate almost all.

Comment: Not every function can be integrated. More rules => more function you will be able to integrate.

Comment: I'm talking about the integrable functions. Consider the set of all integrable functions, Prof. claims that this total 40 transformations and calculations are enough to solve all of them. see the update